# Simple Circuit Giving Weird V=IR Calculation

Tags: voltage, current, resistance

I'm new to electronics and learning as I go along.

This is my "baby" circuit: a 1.5V AA battery (at 1.61V) whose terminals are connected to a 10K ohm resistor on a breadboard.

When I take a current measurement across the terminals of the resistor, I get 210-230ma on my multimeter.

As an experiment to determine voltage from the equation, when I plug the current and resistance values into the V=I*R equation:

V = .22 * 10,000

V = 2,200

This doesn't make sense, since my battery is 1.61V.

I have verified my resistor to be 10.3K ohms.

Can someone please help and explain what the problem seems to be?

Comment: Are you placing your multimeter in series to take the current measurement?

Comment: You say ' _across the terminals _ '. Are you measuring on each side of the resistor?

Comment: Current meter goes in series with the resistor! You are very lucky your battery is so flat (or crummy), some can output amperes and blow the meter fuse. If the source is more significant and the meter unfused, you can create a safety hazard.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany is saying that by setting your multimeter to measure current and then placing it on either side of the resistor,  you are shorting the terminals of your battery through the meter. Do some research on how to take measurements with a multimeter. Current is measured in series, voltage is measured in parallel.

Comment: Besides the comments about measuring current incorrectly, you would need to measure such tiny currents with a really good meter. An inexpensive "3-1/2" digit meter lowest scale is 200 mA, or reading 199.9 mA. The current you are trying to read is about 0.15 mA. This will be barely measurable with a cheaper meter.

Comment: It appears I was measuring current in parallel, whoops. I placed one multimeter probe on one resistor terminal and the other probe on the other terminal of the resistor.

Answer (score 3):

Another way to look at it would be like this:

$$ V/I = R $$

V is known and so is I \$ 1.61V/0.22A = 7.3Ω \$ which is probably the resistance of your battery, meter and wires in between. You are probably shorting out the resistor by measuring across the resistor in current mode.

While measuring in current mode you need to place the meter in series with the resistor, not measure across it. Since I'm not at your bench I don't know exactly what is going on.

Another way to make the current measurement is use the resistor and measure the voltage across it.

$$ V_{res}/R = I  $$

which is not going to be exactly the same as the voltage across your battery (there are small losses from the cables) but it will be close.

It should be something like \$ 1.61V/10300Ω = 0.000156A\$ or 156uA

Keep in mind that your batter voltage will drop when more current is drawn from it (it has internal source resistance, batteries are not ideal voltage sources).

Comment: Correctly stated +1